# how to change order for pages on units coursepress

Tags: wordpress

Can anyone help me to changing order for pages under unit of each course,please your help will be really appreciate.I tried a lot but fail to get the meta value for each pages.

Comment: What did you have tried ? Show your code, please.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem well, this plugin may be a solution: https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-page-ordering/

Comment: Hi Nerijus Thanks for your reply,but this plugin will help for pages but the coursepress is a plugin in which i have to set reordering for the pages under the unit section.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having this problem, you are one of many.

The only solution I have found so far is this work-around plugin, I believe it is called "Emanaku's Reordering of Pages in CoursePress Pro 2.0". Here's a link to the WPMUDev topic: https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/coursepress-plugin-for-reordering-pages

Read the description carefully, you need at least CoursePress version 2. Note - this plugin is probably going to stop working in the future, as it depends on the current structure of CoursePress which is likely to change dramatically.

Comment: You should and more context to the link.  What is the plugin name, etc.  If the link dies your answer become worthless.